# Woocommerce Product details page remove add to cart and put Email Button

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In my woocommerce website for simple products, I need to remove Add to Cart, quantity box and put a Email Button with mail to link. Can anyone please help me how can i do it.

Comment: I think your question is more suitable for another SE website - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Add This code snippet in active theme function.php file

```
// For remove Add to cart button
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart');



    // add inquiry button into every product
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'prfx_add_inquiry_button', 10); // catalog page
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'prfx_add_inquiry_button', 30); // single product page
    function prfx_add_inquiry_button() {
        $current_product_id = get_the_ID(); // get ID of the current post
        $current_product_title = get_the_title(); // get the title of the current post
        $product = wc_get_product( $current_product_id ); // get the product object
                echo $current_product_title;
                echo '<a href="mailto:test@example.com?subject=Inquiry for product id:$current_product_id" class="button">Inquiry</a>';
                echo '</a>';
    }
```